# Exporting html table created by PHP into Excel

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table, export-to-excel

I have a html table created by PHP using mysql and I used "table to excel" JQUERY method to export it but the problem that I ran into is printed variables from Mysql into this table are not exporting to excel I mean when I export the table to Excel I can see just the headers or column names and all html variables not php variables

JQUERY script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
      var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
      }
    })()
</script>
```

html table created by php :

```
 <?php
        $tbl_name="form_0"; // Table name   
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `{$tbl_name}` WHERE `uni_id`='{$_SESSION["uni_id"]}'   ");
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);

                ?>  
                    <table class='styled-table' id="testTable" cellspacing='0' border='1' rules="groups">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>sample 1</th>
                                <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>sample 2</th>
                                <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>sample 3</th>
                                <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>sample 4</th>
                                <th  scope='col' style='font-size:13px;'>sample 5 گواهی</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                <?php   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>     

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' style=' padding: 5px; width: 100px;margin-right:2px;margin-left:2px;' type='text' name='morabi' id='morabi' value= "<?php echo $row['morabi']; ?>" ></td>
                                <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' style=' padding: 5px; width: 100px;margin-right:2px;margin-left:2px;' type='text' name='ostadyar' id='ostadyar' value= "<?php echo $row['ostadyar']; ?>" ></td>
                                <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' style=' padding: 5px; width: 100px;margin-right:2px;margin-left:2px;' type='text' name='daneshyar' id='daneshyar' value= "<?php echo $row['daneshyar']; ?>" ></td>
                                <td align='center'><input  class='styled-input' style=' padding: 5px; width: 100px;margin-right:2px;margin-left:2px;' type='text' name='ostad' id='ostad' value= "<?php echo $row['ostad']; ?>" ></td>
                                <td align='center'><a      class='styled-input' style=' padding: 7px; margin-right:2px;margin-left:2px;color:#008AB8;' href="<?php echo '../../../../uploads/form_0/'.$row['govahi']; ?>"  target="_blank")">view</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                <?php } ?>                              

                    </table>
                    <div class='cleaner h20'></div>

                    <input class='styled-input_2' style="width:105px;" type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="export to excel" />

                    <div class='cleaner h20'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove input tag from your table and echo your php variables directly like below it will work.

```
<td class='styled-input' style='width: 100px;'><?php echo $row['morabi']; ?></td>
```